# present participle as an adverbial?

Tags: grammar, past-participles, adverbial-phrases

The use of some words in English grammar resources is expressed as follows:

1-) I passed the exam **by studying.**

2-) I cut the paper **using** scissor.

Why isn't '' by '' added in 2 ? or Why isn't the word '' by '' removed from the other sentence?

Comment: **Scissors** is always plural. You could say _by using_, but _with [a pair of] scissors_ would be more usual.

Comment: Syntactically, ***using** scissors* is equivalent to ***by** scissors* or ***with** scissors*. There are many contexts where we can optionally use *multiple* prepositions - *Come [over] to me, Get off [of] the bus, Climb [up] to the top,...* In your case, we *could* say you [*did it **by using**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22did+it+by+using%22) scissors.* But if you *did it **with** scissors* you couldn't include another preposition.